# Highline padding inserted password with random number of *

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that ask for password using highline/import:

```rb
ask("Enter your password:  ") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
```

I want to add a random number of * to the output once the user finishes to input their password. That's because the output is captured and I don't want to reveal the length of the password. As a requirement I can't disable the echo.

Comment: Why don't you want to always return the same amount of `*`s? Can you show an example of some of the possible outputs?

Comment: While the user is typing an * will be output for each character. The output of this ruby script is stored and I want, once the user finished inserting input (carriage return) to pad a random number of * so the log will contain a string of * that does not reveal the password length

Comment: If you can't disable the echo then the asterisks are going to be pretty pointless. `hunter2********`.

Comment: That's not my requirement. I can't disable the echo. I just want to add random number of asterisks when the user presse enter.

Answer (score -1):

You can just multiply `'*'` by a random value. Import SecureRandom:

```rb
require 'securerandom'
```

Then in that block:

```rb
q.echo = '*' * SecureRandom.rand(5..15)
```

Comment: That will add * while the user is typing. I want to add a random number of asterisks after the user press carriage return.

Comment: You said "As a requirement I can't disable the echo." which means you effectively can't do this. Every single password ingestion system suppresses echo on purpose. You could try `print "\b*"` to attempt to obscure it, but this is a fool's errand.

Comment: @tadman i think the OP wants to have regular `*` feedback while entering the password (as shown in the question). But as soon as the user hits return a random amount of `*` should be appended to those existing `*`.

Comment: @Stefan Sure, but without suppressing echo that doesn't do anything. You still see the text.

Comment: I think _"I can't disable the echo"_ means that `q.echo = false` isn't an option which would result in no echo at all. The OP has to keep `q.echo = '*'` which turns the input chars into `*`.

Comment: I do think that the question is clear enough. That's a requirement I'm not asking the best solution (that surely would be to set echo to false). I want to keep the regular feedback with "*" and only when the user hits return pad the output with a random number of "*"

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? If you want to obscure the typing, just do the default and disable echo, no asterisks at all. When you go down this road of being "clever" it makes people think they've mis-typed. If you slap on a random number at the end it doesn't help anyone, nor prevent any snooping.